# Change `&` sign in XSLT

Tags: xslt, latex

Say I have an XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sometag>
Me &amp; you
</sometag>

<othertag>
You &amp; me
</othertag>
```

I want to convert this code into LaTeX using XSLT. When I apply the script

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<apply-templates/>
```

I get

```
Me & you
You & me
```

However, since `&` is an active character in LaTeX, I would rather want the output to become

```
Me \& you
You \& me
```

This is supposed to happen to *all* occurences of `&` in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT isn't actually valid, as **xsl:apply-templates** should really be inside an **xsl:template** of some description.

Having said that, all you need to do is have a template that matches **text()** nodes, and use the xpath function **replace** to replace it.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&amp;', '\\&amp;')" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yeah, I kinda screwed up when I made that working example. But thank you, I'll accept once this becomes possible. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can also use an `xsl:character-map`. This might be easier if you have multiple characters to modify.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" use-character-maps="chars"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:character-map name="chars">
        <xsl:output-character character="&amp;" string="\&amp;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I actually have, so I may end up applying this solution instead, thank you! :-)